# Getting MySQL syntax error in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, gradle, persistence

I'm making a simple application in using Spring Boot with Gradle and trying to connect it to MySQL on my computer. When I run the application I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'load (id integer not null, customer varchar(255), date datetime not null, destin' at line 1

Right now I only have one class, Load and this is what it looks like :

```
@Entity
public class Load {
    public Load(){}
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Customer field must not be blank")
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100, message = "Customer name too long!")
    private String customer;

    @NotBlank(message = "Destination field must not be blank")
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100, message = "Destination name too long!")
    private String destination;

    @NotBlank(message = "Driver field must not be blank")
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50, message = "Driver name too long!")
    private String driver;


    @NotNull
    private Date date;

    public Load(String customer, String destination, String driver, Date date) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.driver = driver;
        this.date = date;
    }
```

I'm not really sure where the issue is with what I'm creating in this class

Comment: Try changing `int id` to `Integer Id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOAD` is a [**reserved keyword**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L) in MySQL, which is why the error message points to name `load` in the SQL statement ("near 'load").

Rename the table by specifying a value name with the `name` attribute of the `@Entity` annotation, e.g.

```
@Entity(name = "customer_load")
public class Load {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use MySQL reserved keyword `Load` as table name that's the problem.

But you can use a reserved keyword also in using backtick character.

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "`load`")
public class Load{
   ...
}
```